# NS3/DCE switch kernels workflow

Tags: ns-3

I am currently working with the ns3 simulator along with the DCE framework to run native applications within the environment of the simulator.
So far I've developing the simulations and loading my current linux kernel with DCE, but now I intend to change my workflow.

For every script simulating traffic in a given topology I want to be able to load different linux kernels to the simulation, as TCP changes considerably from one version to the other.

For example, having a simple traffic exchange simulation named **simulation.cc**, and a set of kernel versions **(3.0-3.8)** for example, I'd like to run the simulation for each kernel in the easiest way possible:

**./simulation -> (with kernel 3.0)** and measure whatever I want.

**./simulation -> (with kernel 3.1)** and measure..

and so on.

So far the only thing I can think of is to download to my computer all  different kernel versions, and then first run the simulation, reboot and change the kernel, and then do the simulation again, etc..

I thought of doing it with a virtual machine but I really need something light, and besides VMware and VirtualBox I don't know which could be the lightest choice, because those simulations constitute a big load for the cpu.

I also wonder, I don't know, if it exists any kernel extension or something that allows you to switch kernels on the fly (I guess not).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: although not specifically related to ns-3, you might be interested in [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2643104): they use QEMU to run different linux kernels to investigate TCP behavior in combination with a network simulation

Comment: Thank you anyway, but I kinda solved it long ago! I will still read it in case I find it useful